# Tutorial: Blast+ results file parsing to fasta file

Tags: blast, ncbi

I'm new to this forum and new to computational analysis, I'm using standalone NCBI Blast+ (blastp) for the first time, and I have the results file in the following format:

Query= Y

Length=6

Subject= X

Length=739

Score = 15.4 bits (28),  Expect = 0.044, Method: Composition-based stats.
 Identities = 5/6 (83%), Positives = 6/6 (100%), Gaps = 0/6 (0%)

Query  1    DDDIPF  6
            D+DIPF
Sbjct  244  DNDIPF  250

But I want to do a multiple alignments of all the hits, for that, I need to extract the sequences in the following fasts format:

> Subject= X

Sbjct  244  DNDIPF

Is there any tool which is helpful to do direct multiple alignments from blast results files or a tool/tutorial to extract the sequences in fasta format to process further. Thanks.

Comment: better ask in https://www.biostars.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the direct output of blast you could use [MView](http://bio-mview.sourceforge.net/), that reformats the results of a sequence database search.
Otherwise another option is to extract the IDs of the sequences you are interested in and perform the alignmetn wioth another tool (e.g. muscle)